# There is no existing directory at \"/home/devops/Dev/Laravel/designhouse/storage/logs\" and it could not be created: Permission denied"

Tags: laravel, docker-compose, permissions, storage, laradock

I use laradock but I have problems with files permissions 
file and directory in laradock_workspace

```
  4 drwxr-xr-x 11 laradock laradock   4096 Sep  7 13:56 app
  4 -rwxr-xr-x  1 laradock laradock   1686 Aug 11 17:44 artisan
  4 drwxr-xr-x  3 laradock laradock   4096 Aug 11 17:44 bootstrap
  4 -rwxr-xr-x  1 laradock laradock   1744 Sep  5 18:30 composer.json
256 -rwxr-xr-x  1 laradock laradock 259279 Sep  5 18:31 composer.lock
  4 drwxr-xr-x  2 laradock laradock   4096 Sep  5 18:33 config
  4 drwxr-xr-x  5 laradock laradock   4096 Aug 11 17:44 database
  4 -rwxr-xr-x  1 laradock laradock   1191 Aug 28 13:56 package.json
  4 -rwxr-xr-x  1 laradock laradock   1215 Aug 11 17:44 phpunit.xml
  4 drwxr-xr-x  2 laradock laradock   4096 Sep  8 14:54 public
  4 -rwxr-xr-x  1 laradock laradock   3651 Aug 11 17:44 README.md
  4 drwxr-xr-x  6 laradock laradock   4096 Aug 11 17:44 resources
  4 drwxr-xr-x  2 laradock laradock   4096 Sep  8 06:29 routes
  4 -rwxr-xr-x  1 laradock laradock    563 Aug 11 17:44 server.php
  4 drwxr-sr-x  6 laradock laradock   4096 Sep  2 17:19 storage
  4 drwxr-xr-x  4 laradock laradock   4096 Aug 11 17:44 tests
  4 drwxr-xr-x 52 laradock laradock   4096 Sep  5 18:31 vendor
  4 -rwxr-xr-x  1 laradock laradock    538 Aug 28 13:56 webpack.mix.js
```

the USER ID and GROUP ID are:

```
root@d2994aedc8e5:/var/www/myproject# id laradock
uid=1000(laradock) gid=1000(laradock) groups=1000(laradock),8377(docker_env)
```

and my file and directory of my project on host

```
drwxr-xr-x 14 devops devops   4096 سپتامبر  8 08:21 .
drwxrwxr-x 10 devops devops   4096 آقۇست   30 01:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x 11 devops devops   4096 سپتامبر  7 18:26 app
-rwxr-xr-x  1 devops devops   1686 آقۇست   11 22:14 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  3 devops devops   4096 آقۇست   11 22:14 bootstrap
-rwxr-xr-x  1 devops devops   1744 سپتامبر  5 23:00 composer.json
-rwxr-xr-x  1 devops devops 259279 سپتامبر  5 23:01 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 devops devops   4096 سپتامبر  5 23:03 config
drwxr-xr-x  5 devops devops   4096 آقۇست   11 22:14 database
-rwxr-xr-x  1 devops devops    220 آقۇست   11 22:14 .editorconfig
-rwxr-xr-x  1 devops devops    934 سپتامبر  8 08:21 .env
-rwxr-xr-x  1 devops devops    778 آقۇست   11 22:14 .env.example
drwxr-xr-x  8 devops devops   4096 سپتامبر  8 19:53 .git
-rwxr-xr-x  1 devops devops    111 آقۇست   11 22:14 .gitattributes
-rwxr-xr-x  1 devops devops    163 آقۇست   11 22:14 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x  2 devops devops   4096 سپتامبر  8 11:44 .idea
-rwxr-xr-x  1 devops devops   1191 آقۇست   28 18:26 package.json
-rwxr-xr-x  1 devops devops   1215 آقۇست   11 22:14 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x  2 devops devops   4096 سپتامبر  8 19:24 public
-rwxr-xr-x  1 devops devops   3651 آقۇست   11 22:14 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  6 devops devops   4096 آقۇست   11 22:14 resources
drwxr-xr-x  2 devops devops   4096 سپتامبر  8 10:59 routes
-rwxr-xr-x  1 devops devops    563 آقۇست   11 22:14 server.php
drwxr-sr-x  6 devops devops   4096 سپتامبر  2 21:49 storage
-rwxr-xr-x  1 devops devops    174 آقۇست   11 22:14 .styleci.yml
drwxr-xr-x  4 devops devops   4096 آقۇست   11 22:14 tests
drwxr-xr-x 52 devops devops   4096 سپتامبر  5 23:01 vendor
-rwxr-xr-x  1 devops devops    538 آقۇست   28 18:26 webpack.mix.js
```

the USER ID and GROUP ID are:

```
/Dev/Laravel/designhouse(master*) » id devops                                                                                                        
uid=1000(devops) gid=1000(devops) groups=1000(devops),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare),998(docker)
```

```
/laradock/.env 

WORKSPACE_PUID=1000
WORKSPACE_PGID=1000
```

and I link storage by this command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

but I cant show any image from storage in the url and I receive 404 error

and after this command 
`php artisan opimize`
show this error:

```
UnexpectedValueException
There is no existing directory at "/home/devops/Dev/Laravel/designhouse/storage/logs" and it could not be created: Permission denied
```

are there any config I do it?

how can I Solve my problem ?

Comment: The directory `storage/logs` need to write permission.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel

Comment: @sta dont  Morin this solution dont work

Comment: @Elie Morin  file and folder in my projec have permission 777